AWS Rekognition OrientationCorrection null
The AWS documentation says

OrientationCorrection The value of OrientationCorrection is always null.
If the input image is in .jpeg format, it might contain exchangeable
image file format (Exif) metadata that includes the image's
orientation. Amazon Rekognition uses this orientation information to
perform image correction. The bounding box coordinates are translated
to represent object locations after the orientation information in the
Exif metadata is used to correct the image orientation. Images in .png
format don't contain Exif metadata.
Amazon Rekognition doesn’t perform image correction for images in .png
format and .jpeg images without orientation information in the image
Exif metadata. The bounding box coordinates aren't translated and
represent the object locations before the image is rotated.

What does this mean as it says its always null but then says it might contain information and has a list of valid values.

The OrientationCorrection field always returns null as it is no longer supported (since 2021). It remains in the API for backwards compatibility with previously released SDKs. The list of possible values is just an artifact of the doc / SDK generation process; those were the previous possible values which need to be retained.
The note in the docs is confusing as it is effectively unrelated. It is saying that Rekognition reads the rotation bit set in the Exif and applies that before processing, so bounding boxes output are relative to that Exif rotation. There is more detail in the image orientation article.
Before it was removed, the OrientationCorrection feature attempted to detect if the image needed to be rotated, by running a detection model on it. But ultimately the results of that were not great, and often conflicted confusingly with the Exif rotation, hence the feature being disabled.
